# Best way for pagination, sorting, filtering an ASP.NET Core MVC that consumes a Web API which uses ADO.NET stored procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: sorting, filter, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API that communicates with a SQL Server database using ADO.Net using stored procedures. This API is consumed in another ASP.NET Core MVC project within the same Visual Studio solution.

What is the best and most reliable way for the MVC project to handle pagination, sorting and filtering functionalities for the displayed results received from the Web API project?

Fully functional source code: https://github.com/krchome/WebAPICoreMVCClient

Regards,
Kaushik

Comment: I have reviewed your code and posted an answer below. I have kept my answer more generic. In your specific case, you need to write more methods in the API to receive parameters like page no, sort key, etc in the API Controller and send the paged and sorted data back to the client.  Also in the client application, a better practice will be write some javascript (Jquery, React or Angular) and call the API directly from the javascript instead of calling the controller and controller calling the API. eg: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-web-api-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code. However the posted article URL doesn't show the API Controller sending paged and sorted data back to the client and so in essence not very useful to prove this point. My project was originally meant to demonstrate how one client MVC app can consume a Web API effectively and it does that. However due to demand from my community which are now expecting these features to have the icing on the cake, i was thinking in that direction. Your suggestion lets me to think making major changes to the design of the API. Is it not possible to paginate, sort the client as is?

Comment: Oh got it, The URL I posted was to show, how we can consume from a Javascript client. Not related to how you do the paging/sorting on the server-side. Of course, you can do that paging and sort in the MVC app, But I would recommend you do the sorting, paging, etc in the Web API instead of doing it in the client which can be very inefficient.

Comment: Ok I see. Can you send some code samples to show a way to do the stuff on the Web API? Also the request format to send from MVC app to get the required response. I do only wish to call the API from MVC only and don't want to go the Javascript path.

Comment: Simply pass them via Query parameters. It's a better practice to pass parameters like paging, sorting, filters, etc via query parameters, so that it can be bookmarked, cached, etc. http://localhost:64798/api/Customer?sort=name

Comment: Please give me a suitable resource to learn and code for paging, sorting and filtering that I can then integrate into my web api application. I know there are lots of resoucres scattered around on the net but can you please point me to a reliable source which I could follow?

Answer (score 1):

When you design an API project separately, the idea is that you will keep all the logic and data fetching activities like sorting, filtering, and paging in the API itself. This makes the API self-contained, cleaner, and faster. UI will be responsible for sending the required parameters to the API which includes page no, sorting key, etc to the API and API will give the correct data. which you can consume from the UI and show it.